# Why doesn't NSFileHandle throw an exception when file no longer exist

Tags: ios, exception, nsfilehandle

I am using NSFileHandle's fileHandleForWritingAtPath to open a handle to a file and write into it (append to the end of it). Since I always need to write into it I never close the handle or check that it's there when writing into it.

I need to support a case were for some reason a third party came and deleted the file, that is I have a valid handle that is going into a file that is no longer there (the kernel should know the handle is bad).
Anticipating this I wrap the call to writeData: with a try catch, I expect the method to throw an exception (why does it return void and not written bytes is beyond me).

It does not.
Why?

Comment: Are you checking the return value of fileHandleForWritingAtPath for nil.

Comment: yes of course, the flow is , open a handle write into it, after some time has passed someone deletes said file.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "someone deletes said file?" I'm asking this because without any more information my guess is that the file is not actually deleted. iOS is - among other things - a Unix-based system, so just removing an entry from a directory does not "delete" the file, and an open handle would keep the file in the file system.

Comment: You are correct, didn't consider that. the file does continue to exist somewhere (I guess the inode has a reference count on it), I can see this by checking the file offsetInFile and see that it grows. Ok then I'll refine my question, can I lock the file?